# How to continually update a label with the current time?

Tags: c#, datetime, clock, hour

I used the following line of code

```
int pp = DateTime.Now.Hour;
```

and it is ok. I wrote

```
label1.text=pp.tostring();
```

for verification and it works, but if I open my form at `19:59` (eg.) in label1 appears `19` and after one minute, when the clock is `08:00`, the value in label1 is not changing and still appears `19`, not `20`.

After that, if I close the form and reopen it, the number in label1 is `20`.

How can I modify the value from datetime.now.hour in real time, while the form is running?
thank you

Comment: A timer with a tick event?

Comment: You need a timer. Check the Timer control.

Comment: Use a Timer and update your UI in its `Tick` handler (provided this is a WinForms question).  Or do the equivalent in WPF or whatever UI library you're using.

Comment: You're only setting the value once, based on that current time. You need to update the value using a Timer or something, if you wish it to be updated in real time.

Comment: I would edit this question to make it clear that you are asking about how to auto-refresh a label; your question has nothing to do with DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the "form" terminology, I'll assume Windows Forms, and the easiest way would be adding a `Timer` component, set a reasonable `Interval` (reasonable meaning *how long is it the maximum you can afford to delay when the hour changes before the label changes*... the higher the interval, the less CPU your process will occupy) on it, and on its `Tick` event, do your:

```
static void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int pp = DateTime.Now.Hour;
  label1.text=pp.tostring();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a `Timer`, and have its `Elapsed` event update `label1.text`. Simply calling `DateTime.Now.Hour` is not enough, as that only updates it once. It does not set a recurring method to constantly update.

```
using System.Timers;

namespace Example {
    static Timer _timer;

    static void Main() {
        _timer = new Timer(1000); // Update every 1 second.
        _timer.Elapsed += UpdateMyLabel;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    static void UpdateMyLabel(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would deduce the Label class and use timer tick for updating the label. Just like in OOP ;)